# Comment links within the same question

Tags: bug, comments, hyperlinks

When I link to a comment within the same question, the link doesn't bring me to the comment itself unless I open it in a new tab/window. Can we fix that?

[I'm using Chrome 17.0]

EDIT: See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126169/166155) for continuation of discussion regarding this issue.

Until this is resolved I recommend using a URL shortener (eg bit.ly) when embedding any links to comments withing the same question.

Comment: Here is a comment.

Comment: [Here](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/950/comment-links-to-the-same-question#comment2168_950) is a link to that comment.

Comment: Try clicking the link, and also trying opening it in a new tab/window.

Comment: FWIW, I get the same behavior. I'm using FF 11.0.

Comment: I got lazy: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126169/166155

Comment: Um.. I'm getting brought straight to that comment. (Chrome 17 on Windows 7)

Comment: @HodofHod, Now, I am too! (Still FF 11.0.) Was this fixed in the past few minutes?

Comment: @IsaacMoses It seems to be working for everyone here (only in the last 2 minutes or so) but not yet on the meta.SO question.

Comment: I imagine someone high up will post an answer soon.

Comment: It's also not working on the main site (yet).

Comment: Any objection to closing this as duplicate of an identical MSO question by the same asker asked near-simultaneously?

Comment: @msh210 Nope. Although here the problem is solved and there not. Maybe the higher ups are working on something

Comment: Fine, I've closed it. I'd close it as a duplicate, but I'd need to specify what it's a duplicate of (on this site). I'd close it as off-topic, but it's not really. So I closed it as "too localized", jokingly, because there's a ("globalized") MSO question.